# « modèles statistique*s* » ou « modèles statistique »

Tags: orthographe, adjectifs, accord

Étant entendu que l'on parle de *la statistique* en temps que discipline et non de *statistiques particulières*, j'aurais tendance à écrire

> […] à l'aide de modèles statistique.

Cependant, j'hésite avec

> […] à l'aide de modèles statistiques.

car on peut y voir un adjectif.

Idem pour les modèles physique(s) ou même mathématique(s) quoique pour ce dernier la question est d'autant plus épineuse que l'usage du terme *mathématique* au singulier est récent (Bourbaki, dans les années 30).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A en croire le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/statistique), c'est la seconde graphie qui semble "la bonne", je n'ai pas vu de spécificités d'accord en nombre sur ce terme. Notamment, en bas de page, parmi leurs exemples, on a

> [...] des méthodes statistiques [...]

**edité :** Pour info, il y a également des institutions qui emploient l'expression en faisant l'accord en nombre, comme le [LPTMS](http://lptms.u-psud.fr/fr), dont j'ai trouvé le lien sur [la page Wikipedia "modèle statistique"](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod%C3%A8le_statistique).

Il existe cependant, quoique beaucoup moins nombreuses, [quelques occurrences](http://www.google.fr/search?q=%22mod%E8les+statistique%22) de "modèles statistique". Probablement peu significatives.

Comment: Il ne faut pas se fier directement au nombre de résultats sur Google. Le 1er n'a rien à voir, le 2nd utilise les 2 (donc vraisemblablement un faute de frappe), le 3ème utilise "modèles statistiques", le 4ème est un titre "*[Tous Modèles] Statistique [...]*", le 5ème dit juste qu'il n'y a pas de résultat pour cette recherche, et le 5ème est visiblement une faute de frappe, puisque le bouquin en question utilise un "s" dans le catalogue de l’éditeur. (Je ne sais pas si tout le monde a les résultats dans le même ordre.)

Comment: @Bruno Tout-à-fait d'accord, je ne donnais le lien que pour se faire une idée, et il n'y a en effet que très peu d'utilisations délibérées de l'expression.

Answer (score 7):

Le fait que *statistique*, *mathématique* ou *physique* soient des disciplines dont les noms peuvent parfois être écrits au singulier ou au pluriel n'a rien à voir avec l'emploi de ce mot dans "*[...] à l'aide de modèles statistiques.*".

Dans cette expression, "*statistiques*" est clairement un adjectif de "*modèles*" et doit s'accorder avec son pluriel.

---

Petite note à côté, puisque j'ai l'impression que la confusion vient peut-être de l'Anglais.

Note that, in English, "*Math models*" tends to stand for "*Mathematical models*", not "*Mathematics models*". (Same for statistical models.)
Here, the nature of the models is also described by an adjective, not a noun.

There may be a few more occurences of "*physics models*" but (a) English has constructs that allow for noun to be glued together in a way that just doesn't work in French and (b), more importantly, it can give a different meaning: for example a "climate model" (two nouns) is a valid expression, but it's a model *of* the climate. As such, it could be a physical, chemical or mathematical climate model. *Physical*, *chemical* and *mathematical* would describe the nature of the model, whereas *climate* would describe what the model is about.

Comment: _climate model_ is translated as _modèle climatique_, again an adjective.

Comment: @Unfrancophone, c'est vrai, mais j'ai l'impression qu'en Anglais, c'est légèrement différent. La même distinction peut aussi se faire en Français: on peut avoir un "*modèle mathématique du climat*". Cependant, il est vrai que l'adjectif peut être utilisé pour la nature du modèle et son sujet. En tous cas, il doit être accordé.

Answer (score 3):

Pour moi il s'agit d'adjectifs et je fais l'accord sans hésiter.

Answer (score 2):

Dans « modèles statistique[s] », « statistique[s] » est un adjectif et non un substantif. Pour le constater, il suffit de considérer des cas isomorphes mais où le substantif et l’adjectif ne peuvent être confondus. Par exemple, les formes suivantes sont clairement inacceptables :

```
modèles astronomie
modèles médecine
analyses syntaxe
```

Les formes correctes correspondantes utilisent des adjectifs épithètes :

```
modèles astronomiques
modèles médicaux
analyses syntaxiques
```

Je ne vois aucune raison de traiter différemment « statistique », « physique » ou « mathématique ».